# Não consigo carregar o CSS e JavaScript na minha página com Node.js

Tags: javascript, css, html5, node.js

Não estou conseguindo carregar o css e o js, ao rodar o servidor recebo a seguinte mensagem no console: "Refused to apply style from '' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled". O que posso fazer para corrigir isso?

Abaixo meu server.js

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json());      
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/views'));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile('index.html')
})

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000,() => {
    console.log(`Rodando ${process.env.PORT || 3000}`);
});
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minha estrutura de pastas acima:

Meu index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Fast Answer</title>
  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../public/bootstrap/node_modules/bootstrap/compiler/bootstrap.css">

  <!-- FONT AWESOME -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css">

  <!-- Material Design Bootstrap -->
  <link href="../public/css/home/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="../public/css/home//mdb.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- JQUERY -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- CSS DA HOME 
  <link href="../bootstrap/node_modules/bootstrap/compiler/homeStyle.css" rel="stylesheet">-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../public/css/home/all.css">

  <!-- ICONE DO SITE -->
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="../public/img/logoIcon.png">
</head>

<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#navbar" data-offset="0">
  <!-- CONTEÚDO -->


  <!-- SCRIPTS -->
  <script src="../public/js/home/navbarChange.js"></script>
  <!-- <script src="js/scrollNav.js"></script> -->
  <script src="../public/js/home/animateBg.js"></script>
  <script src="../public/js/home/popUpLogin.js"></script>

  <!-- BOOTSTRAP SCRIPTS -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../public/js/home/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../public/js/home/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../public/js/home/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../public/js/home/mdb.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente ajustar os *static* da mesma forma que voce fez para as *views* so que para a pasta *public* e depois nos links do arquivo html, remova os `../public/` dos arquivos CSS e JavaScript. Ficaria assim:

Para o `app.js`:

```js
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/views'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

e para os links no HTML:

```html
<link href="css/home/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/home//mdb.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Resposta simples e pratica, tambem funcinou pra mim no Angular 8 com Node.js